# Collapsing a Multiindex DataFrame for Regression

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Multiindexed DataFrame containing the explanatory variables `df` and a DataFrame containing the response variables `df_Y`

```
# Create DataFrame for explanatory variables
np.arrays = [['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'], 
             [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*np.arrays)),
                  columns=['X1', 'X2'])
```

[image]

```
# Create DataFrame for response variables
df_Y = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=['Y'])
```

[image]

I am able to perform regression on just the single level DataFrame with index `foo`

```
df_X = df.ix['foo']    # using only 'foo'
reg = linear_model.Ridge().fit(df_X, df_Y)
reg.coef_
```

**Problem:** However since the `Y` variables is the same for both levels `foo` and `bar`, so we can have twice as many regression samples if we also include `bar`.

[image]

What is the best way to reshape/collapse/unstack the multilevel DataFrame so we can make use of all the data for our regression? **Other levels may have lesser rows that `df_Y`**

*Sorry for the confusing wording, I am unsure of the correct terms/phrasing*

Answer (score 0):

The first index can be dropped and then a join will work:

```
df.index = df.index.drop_level()
df = df.join(df_Y)
```